# ObjC to Swift conversion of NSDictionary to NSObject : AnyObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdictionary

I'm implementing Segment.com's iOS library with Swift and all is working great, just stuck on the code conversion below of the `identify` method:

ref: https://segment.com/docs/libraries/ios/#identify

```
[[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] identify:@"userId"
                                traits:@{ @"email": @"em@il.com" }];
```

where `traits` is an `NSDictionary *, optional`

Xcode tells me (typeahead hints) that in Swift it translates to:

```
SEGAnalytics.sharedAnalytics().identify(userId: String!, traits: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
```

As a new Swift developer I'm struggling to get the syntax right to send an object into traits.  How can I send in my set of predefined dictionary of optionals into the traits section? Something like: `{email : email!, name : fullName!}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to use like this

```
var traitsDic : NSDictionary! = [ "email": "em@il.com", "firstName" : "Name" ]
var traits = traitsDic as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

SEGAnalytics.sharedAnalytics().identify(userId: String!, traits: traits)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Dharmbir, with the brackets on the NSDictionary this worked perfectly.

Comment: @EPage_Ed I don't know about swift 2 but it was working in old swift.

Comment: Why is this necessary in the first place?